# Validating password using javascript and razor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to make a simple login form with password encrypting and validating in asp-mvc.

I have the following login form (partial code only):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        //some fields
        ... 

        // password
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        //some fields
        ... 
}
```

In addition, I have the following javascript code (I know that the encryption is not the safest that way but that's more than enough for me)

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function (e) {
    var pass = $("#Password").val();
    var passMD5 = CryptoJS.MD5(pass);
    $("#Password").val(passMD5);
});
```

And a C# ViewModel which have the following attribute

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Can't leave password field empty")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

When someone enters a password I encrypt the password and then send it to the server but then the validation is calculated for the encrypted password.

How can I perform some validations on the password field and have the errors be displayed in the the Html.ValidationMessageFor spot?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your question, but just to keep you updated, **NEVER** rely on client-side hashing. [Its very dangerous in the event of a server breach](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53594/why-is-client-side-hashing-of-a-password-so-uncommon) even though it may seem to be in the client's interests.

Comment: `MD5` is not encryption, it is a one-way hash function. Additionally it is not considered secure just to hash the password with `MD5`. You need to use a better hash function, actually an HMAC with a salt and iterations to slow down an attacker. `password_hash`, Bcrypt` or `PBKDF2` are both good password hashing functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want validation to happen on client side itself means try calling these two js along with the latest jquery library..If any of the field doesnt satisfy the condition means it will show the error message on the client side itself and it will not hit the server side coding..

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.1/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the form before you change the password by doing the following:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function (e) {
    if (!$("#loginForm").valid()) {
        return false;
    }
    var pass = $("#Password").val();
    var passMD5 = CryptoJS.MD5(pass);
    $("#Password").val(passMD5);

 });
```

If validation fails you will see the client side message, and if it succeeds an encrypted password will be passed to the server.